# Upgrade from Zurb Foundation 4 to 5 in ASP.NET MVC4.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, zurb-foundation

I am new to SASS and Zurb Foundation but I need to upgrade an ASP.NET MVC4 project using Zurb Foundation 4 with SASS to Foundation 5. As far as I know, there is no Nuget package for Foundation 5 yet so I had to download the Foundation 5 with SASS version from https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/scss-standaloneand manually added to my project and build solution. In the `packages.config` file, I still see this

`<package id="Foundation4.Core.Sass" version="4.1.6" targetFramework="net45" />
 <package id="Foundation4.MVC4.Sass" version="1.2.416" targetFramework="net45" />`

Should I also modify the `packages.config` manually to Foundation5 or is there any other way to upgrade to Foundation 5? I already have Web Workbench installed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just updated my MVC project from 4 to 5. There is a nuget package for ver 5 out now. I uninstalled Foundation 4 first(be sure to take a backup if you have made changes directly in  a foundation file). Then I installed the new Foundation 5 package. There a few changes so you should follow the migration guide provided here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html. Good luck!